# How to link a ComboBox to a Column of DataGrid Control in WinForms? - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datagrid, dataset

Here is a part of my code:

```
// building a dataset
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Stud_Prog");

DataTable student = new DataTable("Student");
DataColumn stud_ID = student.Columns.Add("Student_ID", typeof(int));
DataColumn stud_name = student.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
DataColumn stud_surname = student.Columns.Add("Surname", typeof(string));
DataColumn stud_grade = student.Columns.Add("Grade", typeof(string));
stud_ID.AutoIncrement = true;
stud_ID.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
stud_ID.Unique = true;
student.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { stud_ID };

DataTable grade = new DataTable("Grade");
DataColumn grad_ID = grade.Columns.Add("Grade_ID", typeof(int));
DataColumn grad_gradeType = grade.Columns.Add("Grade Type", typeof(string));
grade.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { grad_ID }; 

grade.Rows.Add(1, "A");
// ...

student.Rows.Add(null, "AAA", "AAA");
// ...

ds.Tables.Add(student);
ds.Tables.Add(grade);
ds.Relations.Add("StudentGradeRelation", ds.Tables[1].Columns[0], ds.Tables[0].Columns[3]);

DataGrid studentGrid = new DataGrid();
DataGrid gradeGrid = new DataGrid();
// adding to the form
// ...

studentGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
gradeGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];

// ...
```

I need Grade column cells of Student table to look like ComboBoxes that would offer me to choose one of the grade types contained inside the Grade table.

Comment: http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-combobox.htm

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, it's not DataGridView. It's DataGrid, it doesn't have those properties.

Comment: [Complete working example](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/05/27/c-data-binding-example-with-adapters-and-datagridview/)

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe the `DataGrid` is a WPF control. Is there some reason you have to use the WPF control in a “win forms” environment? I am just guessing that using this control in a “win forms” environment is doable, however, I am confident the `DataGridView` will be easier to implement considering the environment. In addition, the posted code is nice… however; I do not see anything in it pertaining to a combo box column… what have you tried?

Comment: @JohnG, Does DataGridView support viewing related tables?

Comment: Without going into detail as to what a `DataGridView` can or cannot do I will reference the last sentence in the question… _”I need Grade column cells of Student table to look like ComboBoxes that would offer me to choose one of the grade types contained inside the Grade table.”_ … this is easily done with a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. Can you be more specific as to what a `DataGrid` can do in this situation that a `DataGridView` cannot?

Comment: @JohnG, I agree that it is easier to use DataGridView and DataGridViewComboBoxColumn for making ComboBox columns. The problem is that, as far as I know, DataGridView has no tools for viewing child tables in the same control. DataGrid has. I need this feature or at least a tool that allow me to view related tables. So I think it's better for me to use the DataGrid control.

Comment: You mean a child relationship like the combo box described in the question? As I previously stated… what you want to do in the question can be easily done using two data tables as you describe and one grid with a combo box column. The data source for the student grid is the students data table, the grid combo box column’s data source is the grades table. I could be wrong but a grid is a grid, the “relation” is built externally of the grid, usually a data set, sql database etc... creates the relation THEN displays it to the grid.

Comment: I am not trying to dissuade you from using a `DataGrid`, by all means use it if you choose. I am simply suggesting that a `DataGridView` is going to be a heck of a lot easier to implement in a “win forms” application. Pick your own poison ;-)

Comment: @JohnG, ok, maybe I will use two different DataGridViews then. Thank you!